# How to decide if propositional function is complete

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have two 3-ary propositional functions given by the table

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
v(a) & v(b) & v(c) & v(f(a, b, c)) & v(g(a, b, c)) \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

And I need to decide which of these functions are complete.
I made some googling but I didn't get the way how to solve such type of tasks.
Books say that $L(\vee,\wedge,\neg)$, $L(\wedge,\neg)$, ... are complete and $L(\wedge)$, $L(\vee)$... are not. But how to apply this on the functions given by table?

I gues I need to make propositional formula from $f$ and $g$. Am I right? If so what's next?

Comment: $v(g(a,b,c))$ is the *minority* conncetive : $v(g(a,b,c))$ always
disagrees with the majority of $v(a), v(b), v(c)$. See Enderton, **Exercises 4**, page 52 : is **not** complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try exploiting the fact that we know that : $\lnot, \land$ is *complete*.

The ternary connective $g(a,b,c)$ is the *minority* connective : $v(g(a,b,c))$ always disagrees with the majority of $v(a),v(b),v(c)$.

We can formally set :

> $v(g(a,b,c))=1$ **iff** $v(a)+v(b)+v(c) \le 1$.

We can define $\lnot$, because $v(g(a,a,a))=1$ **iff** $v(a)=0$.

But we cannot define $a \land b$, because $v(a \land b)=1$ **iff** $v(a)+v(b) = 2$.

Thus, it is **not** complete.

---

It seems to me that $f(a,b,c)$ is *complete*.

We can formally set :

> $v(f(a,b,c))=[1-v(a)v(c)][1-v(b)v(c)]$.

In this way, we can define $\lnot$, because $v(f(a,a,a))=1$ **iff** $v(a)=0$.

We can check also that $f(a,b,c)$ is equivalent to : $\lnot c \lor (\lnot a \land \lnot b)$.

Obviously : $\lnot a \land \lnot a \equiv \lnot a$; thus $f(a,a,c)$ is $\lnot a \lor \lnot c$ i.e. $\lnot (a \land c)$ that is NAND, or [Sheffer stroke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheffer_stroke) and we know that it is complete.

Comment: Oh that's not obvious at all. Thank you, you helped me a lot